# Purpose of `n` field added to tables by `table.pack`? Heck, why does `table.pack` even exist?

Tags: lua, lua-table

Title says it all. I want to know why Lua adds an `n` field to tables when using `table.pack()`.

Literally this is how you can implement this:

```
function pack(...)
    return { n = select("#", ...), ... }
end

-- pretty useless
```

I don't see a point as you can use `{}` to construct a table and `#tbl` to get how many elements there are in a table.

```
local tbl = table.pack('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
print(tbl.n, #{ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' }) -- 4    4

-- Same thing
```

If you use `next` to traverse a table constructed with `table.pack`, it really ruins iteration. Ofc you can use `ipairs` but for those who don't? Oh and length operator won't count that `n`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`table.pack()`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-table.pack) need not return a sequence. It only does so iff all arguments are non-`nil`.

Thus, if you want to reverse it, you need the `"n"`-member in the general case.

```
table.unpack(t, 1, t.n)
```

And despite the implementation being pretty trivial, `table.pack()` is still a useful abstraction.

Answer (score 0):

```lua
local tbl = table.pack('a', 'b', nil, 'd', nil)
print(tbl.n, #{ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' }) -- 5    2

-- Very much *not* the same thing
```

There you have it. It's easy to implement, yes, but that doesn't mean you should have to implement it by hand for every project.

> If you use `next` to traverse a table constructed with `table.pack`, it really ruins  iteration.

Yes, that's why you *don't* use `next` to iterate sequences. Use `ipairs` instead, its what it's meant for.

1. `next` is slower than ipairs (both PUC and JIT)
2. `next` doesn't iterate in order
3. using `ipairs` is a Lua convention

> Oh and length operator won't count that n.

By default it doesn't, but you can just write a metamethod that does that, it's really no big deal.

```lua
local meta = { __len = function(self) return self.n or rawlen(self) end }
print(#setmetatable(table.pack('a', 'b', nil, 'd', nil))) -- 5
```